# Java rectangle detection

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, shapes

Now i'm working on some image processing project, and i'm stuck. 
I can't find proper algorithm to detect rectangles on the image.

Is there any methods in Java which will be helpful to me? Or implementations of Hough transform for rectangles?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [openCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_detect.html)? [`detect()`](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_detect.html) is what you want. You'll have to train the classifier on your own, however generating rectangles to train it on shouldn't be too hard :-)